# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 3,Token in error = Employee_ID ]

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute the below query but iam getting the folowing error.

```
Create table Employee(
Employee_ID char(5)Primary key, 
First_Name char(20) NOT NULL,
Last_Name char(20) NOT NULL,
Phone_Number varchar(20) NULL  
);

Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 26302
> Create table Employee(
Employee_ID char(5)Primary key, 
First_Name char(20) NOT NULL,
Last_Name char(20) NOT NULL,
Phone_Number varchar(20) NULL  
)
```

The specified data type is not valid. [ Data type (if known) = char ]

Answer (score 2):

If the database you are using is some version of Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition (which the error message would suggest) the error stems from the fact that particular database doesn't support the`char`/`varchar`data types as it's purely unicode based. What you need to do is to use the corresponding unicode data types`nchar`/`nvarchar`like this:

```
Create table Employee (
Employee_ID nchar(5) Primary key, 
First_Name nchar(20) NOT NULL,
Last_Name nchar(20) NOT NULL,
Phone_Number nvarchar(20) NULL  
);
```

For reference: [Data Types Supported in SQL Server CE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx)